# What to do with a question which has non-working code which actually works fine?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40384707/903011) and provided two solutions which do not work (hoping that someone would have another solution).

When comments "it works for me" started to come in, I tried again the code in the question and ... it works. I do not know why, when building the question I quadrupled-checked. Anyway.

What do do with such a question?

- it is reasonably useful (I believe) and covers a reasonable use case. It could be left as it so that other, when searching, find it.
- there will probably be no answer as the answer is in the question.

Should I leave it as it?

Or completely reorganize it? (in the form of a minimalistic one-liner question and move my code to an answer)

Or delete it as it may seem useful only to me?

Comment: There is a close reason for that "*This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*" It is probably best to delete it.

Comment: @ayhan: OK. The only part which bothers me is *this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers* as the solution in the question is (IMHO) useful. But be it, I will delete.

Comment: @WoJ If the solution in the question is useful and there isn't an existing question about it, you can always rework it into a new self-answered question.

Answer (score 3):

We have a close reason for these kind of questions:

> This question was caused by a problem that can *no longer be reproduced* or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, *this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.* This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

(emphasis mine).

We're very happy that you solved your problem, but that's not really why we are here: we're here to build a Q&A site which is aimed at *future readers*. So deleting your question is a good option here.

Another option (which is usually not feasible for 'no longer reproducable' questions) would be to remove the 'solution' from the question itself, and publish it as an self-answered question. I would remove the 'not working' part, then. Because there are no (non-deleted) answers to the question, you have a bit more freedom to rework it. Alternatively, you could post this Q+A in a new question.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment, the only part which bothers me is *this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers* as the solution in the question is (IMHO) useful. But I will follow the suggestion and delete it.